# undefined function or variable error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

I am trying to install support packages for Computer Vision System Toolbox in MATLAB but when I type "visionSupportPackages" it gives undefined function or variable error. I do have the toolbox for it. I am new to MATLAB so please point out anywhere I could have gone wrong even if it is minute. Thanks. I use MATLAB R2012a.

Comment: Do you use Matlab R2014b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

visionSupportPackages is not available in R2012, see here http://nl.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html